# Better use for this duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Now dual Canadian and EU citizen- Does ESTA need to know?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66072/36405)

This question got marked as a duplicate. Yes, the duplicate question does answer the underlying problem, but I think the question could be far more useful as a "my citizenship changed, does this affect esta?"-kind of question, including non-Canadian dual nationals. Maybe the question could be edited to reflect this? Also, the questions are different, so is it really a duplicate? [If an answer works for two different questions, should we mark the new question as a duplicate?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1525/36405)

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe the question could be edited to reflect this?

NO. [See](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11486): *do not: Change the meaning of the post*.

> the questions are different, so is it really a duplicate?

NO:

> Don't close a question that *happens to have the same answer as another question.*

[Joel Spolsky♦](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/744/4995)