# Question does not get answered by duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This question: [I have booked a flight from the USA to China and am a dual national. How do I avoid China getting to know this?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66740/36405)

It got marked as a duplicate, but as I pointed out in the comments, the duplicate question does not help the asker. The duplicate does not cover OP's situation, who has already bought tickets and probably has the means to make his trip work (greencard), which really makes his question different.

Ironically, this question is on the meta front page: [Can we be more careful in marking duplicates on questions that are related but ask for or about different things?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3482/36405)

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this keeps happening... there seems to be a hardcore clique of closevote addicts. I guess because closevotes are initially anonymous, certain individuals think "This has no consequences *for me*, so who cares if it has consequences for other people". I've voted to re-open, but it usually takes days to reach 5 re-open votes.

Comment: The proper answer to OP's situation is to forget about his current ticket and follow the instructions in the duplicate question (flying through a third country). Anything else is potentially risky.

Comment: @JonathanReez Well, that doesn't make my point less valid. OP still has a different question which the canonical doesn't cover. A possible answer could be "it's risky, because [enter reasons]. Forget about your tickets and book new ones. See canonical for how to do it instead." Just closing as duplicate does not help.