# For visa questions, is two different specific destinations enough to rule out deemed 'duplication' even where the destinations are not relevant?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Apparently:

[Does an Indian need a visa to transfer from Paris ORY to Paris CDG?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transfer-from-paris-ory-to-paris-cdg)

is not a duplicate of:

[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

(I was one of five who voted to close on that basis.)

Transfer between two major airports serving the same city arises not only for Paris and since of relevance to many travellers might perhaps justify being considered a 'special case'.

However the underlying issue is that to escape ORY (even to a different terminal at the same airport) Immigration must be crossed. Landside requires a Schengen visa (for those requiring a visa) and hence the *destination* is of no relevance for the issue.

**Is two different specific destinations enough to rule out deemed 'duplication' or is ORY>CDG a special (not necessarily unique) case?**

For example:

Does an Indian need a visa to transfer from Paris ORY to Paris LBG?
Does an Indian need a visa to transfer from Paris ORY to 8 Place de la Concorde, Paris?
Does an Indian need a visa to transfer from Paris ORY to 6 Place de la Concorde, Paris?

There is a lot about what does/does not/should constitutes a duplicate [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/a-friendly-reminder-that-duplicates-should-be-the-same-question-not-different-q) but my question is restricted to consideration only of destinations for visa purposes and assumes an answer (to at least one of the Qs) of a general nature, such as [@Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/30570/4995)'s, which includes a section:

> Can you transfer without leaving the international area of the airport?

(Where, for example, *specific* nationality is not relevant either.)

Answer (score 2):

All we need is a canonical on transfers during transit, so I've simply changed the title of the existing question to [Does one need a visa to transfer between two airports during a transit through the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/does-one-need-a-visa-to-transfer-between-two-airports-during-a-transit-through-t)

Now any similar questions can either go to the master question (general transit situation) or the sub-canonical (transfer during transit).

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny issue which makes the two questions slightly different. But that tiny issue does not mean that each of your suggestions would be a valid question, too.

The Question ‘[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)’ is rather short and sweet.

> I found many related questions on this site but I am still not sure about the rules. How can I decide if I need a visa to transit?

From the way both the title and the question are worded, it seems very much okay to ask (and answer) this based on:

> Do I need a transit visa if my itinerary is DME–CDG–JFK?

I.e. that it concerns cases where you *arrive* and *leave* the Schengen area *via* a single airport. This is the usual way that *transit* (or *layover)* is understood as far as I know.

The question you are referring to is slightly different in that *a change of airports* is required. The initerary could have been DME–ORY–CDG–JFK.

As was commented and answered, you *have* to use ground transport to get from one to the other. That, in my eyes, makes it sufficiently different from a simple transit/layover question which is what the other seems to be asking. Thus, a question of that kind should serve as a *different* canonical dupe target — however, it can serve as a dupe target for all such itineraries, whether it is LHR to LGW, TXL to SXF, BWI to IAD, NRT to HND or any other combination of two physically different airports.

To be honest, I’m not sure if there shouldn’t be a third canonical dupe for questions concerning itineraries such as DME–FRA–CDG–JFK. These may be seen as two transits in the Schengen area by non-Schengen laymen, while it is actually very much like the ORY–CDG question (except that there are planes from one airport to the other).

However, this answer is based on the **current situation.** Instead of having a number of different canonical dupes, we can also edit our canonical dupe to *explicitly* cover all cases. IMHO, that should actually be the preferred path to take.

Comment: @pnuts The Q needs clarification first, imho.

Comment: @pnuts The OP is open to discussion in chat but the “clarification” seemed like a lengthy development on a side issue that might require a separate question. When an edit becomes so long and complicated it's becoming difficult to even follow what was changed. And as you note, it's not a wiki, I never intended for everybody to come and add stuff.

Comment: @Jan I am completely confused by your answer. Both the change of airports within the same city and the “internal“ Schengen flight situations are covered in the canonical question (third paragraph of Q2). Maybe canonical questions are a bad idea all around (to be honest I created that one without enthusiasm because it seemed to be the direction consensus was going at the time) but if the criteria is whether the answer already covers the situation, then this one most definitely does. Where did you get the impression that any of this is about arriving and leaving Schengen visa a single airport?

Comment: @Relaxed The canonical **question** does not cover anything. The canonical **answer** might, but duplicates are supposed to be the same or a similar **question.** The entire content of the canonical question is quoted above. That needs to be the first point of discussion.

Comment: @Jan Well if questions don't cover anything why do you bring it up? You infer that the other question “seems” to be asking about something then you tell me it does not cover anything. What are we even talking about then?That Q&A covers all this and much more, it just does not make sense to single out the change of airport as making a difference in any way. Now regarding identical questions vs. adequate answers, I made that point many times. That's an objection to canonical questions in general and the reason why I am lukewarm about them. But your answer still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Relaxed I’m saying that I cannot judge from the content ‘I found many related questions on this site but I am still not sure about the rules. How can I decide if I need a visa to transit?’ whether it covers a change of airport or not. In fact, I have strong difficulties judging whether a question that fits extremely well into a comment actually asks anything. The canonical question should first ask all the questions (in principle) that the answer is covering. Then we can re-decide whether the other question OP brought up is a dupe of the canonical one.

Comment: I am actually very much in favour of keeping canonical questions and answers but it should be evident from the canonical question itself (and *not* by looking at the answer) whether whatever is supposed to be a dupe is asked by that canonical question or not.

Comment: @Jan This is becoming absurd. That's exactly what this question does if you read it honestly. It's quite clear that the intent is to cover all cases of transit, with or without change of airports. Of course you can't tell if it's about one or the other, because the whole point of a canonical question is being about both (and a whole host of other things). So it's not explicitly about one or the other *because* it's canonical, just as it's not about a specific airport, a specific citizenship, etc. The more specific you make it, the less canonical it is, simple as that.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no way for someone who doesn't already know the rules and the answer to guess that the change of airport is the salient factor so it would be a silly to use as a criteria for keeping or closing a question or splitting them. One good thing about the canonical question is that it provides a guide for the readers to discover what matters, even if they did not know it beforehand. Ideally, you wonder about transit and visas in general, you read this and you think “aha, it matters that I switch from Orly to Roissy, I didn't realise that”.

Comment: @Relaxed Call it absurd if you wish but I read that line time and time again and I still cannot tell from it which cases it asks. Is there any reason why a canonical question can’t be e.g. ‘Do I need a visa if I change planes at one airport? Do I need one if I need to change airports, too? If one of my connections goes from Schengen to Schengen, do I need one?’

Comment: If I’m in the asker’s shoes, I would look at that question and think ‘No, that’s just about transit at a single airport. I’m changing airports, that makes a difference!’ Especially consider somebody who is not familiar with the SE model of providing comprehensive answers.

Comment: @Jan Of course, you cannot tell, I just told you why. But you are still happy to assume it's about a transit at a single airport. Now, can you tell or can you not? That's what makes no sense in this whole discussion.

Comment: @Relaxed Because it’s the simplest and easiest explanation. Occam’s razor. If I may guess, over 90 % of transits are those at a single airport.

Comment: To the broader question, it's silly to have a canonical question that reads “Do I need a visa if I change plane at one airport?" because it's not obvious why that would be a particularly salient fact, especially if you don't already know the answer. And why single that factor out? You could say the same about the airline (low-cost or not), the citizenship, the airport (Tegel, anyone?) and then the question is not canonical at all. If you follow that line of reasoning, you never close anything as a duplicate of a canonical question because canonical question *must* cover several cases.

Comment: @Jan Yet I deliberately phrased the question to be broader. You just don't want to read honestly and to pretend it seems to be asking something more specific for the sake of making a point. That has very little to do with Occam's razor.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes it must cover several cases, but *it’s wording should be clear enough that it covers several cases.* The canonical question does not sound like it covers several cases.

Comment: @Jan But it is, it covers transit in general. In fact, the whole paragraph makes that completely explicit “How do I find out?“ also implies ”What should I pay attention to?” and “not sure about the rules” even implies it should cover *all* the rules. How could that not cover transit through several airports? You still haven't explained how that particular detail is different from any other detail that is deliberately left out. The rest is something that you imagined to beat a straw man and completely unhelpful.