# Does this count as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

So I was able to answer [Does having a TSA Pre-Check member in your flight reservation increase the chances that everyone gets Pre-Check?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/134473/4188) from [Can others in my party go through TSA PreCheck?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56938/4188) . The answers to the latter except for one do not even the question rather answer the qustion asked here, more or less. Do we keep my answer or close it as a duplicate? In a perfect world the wrong answers would be migrated to the right question but I do not think SE has the tools to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As outlined in [A friendly reminder that duplicates should be the same QUESTION, not different questions with similar answers](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/a-friendly-reminder-that-duplicates-should-be-the-same-question-not-different-q), we don't consider questions duplicates if they contain the same answer but a different question. Therefore we can keep both questions open.

Comment: This is demonstrated by the fact that you didn't vote to close this meta question as a duplicate, even though the answer is the same.

Comment: On Meta Stack Exchange, however, it's perfectly acceptable to close questions as duplicates if the answers are the same but the questions are merely related. (As my main site is Meta.SE, I often get tripped up by this policy on other sites.)