# Improving duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

Being new here I've answered a few questions before they've been marked as duplicate. However, on checking the original answer, on a couple of occasions I believe my answer was still appropriate and not duplicated by one of the answers on the original question. I've also seen a couple of other questions that have been marked as duplicate but I don't think the answers were complete.

Is there, or should there be a way to move an answer on the duplicated question over to the canonical answer, or should the answer be answered again on the canonical answer?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there has been some controversy ([historically](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/698/32134) and [recently](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3638/32134)) on what is a dupe and what is not. You will soon (from 3k rep) have close/re-open rights and join that fun. If you feel it is a false dupe, comment, flag for re-opening, alert other people in chat and vote. IMHO that is good style, motivates new users to come back and makes useful contributions to this place.

In the case were a question has been rightly marked as a duplicate but your answer is still contributing beyond the answers in the dupe, by all means copy your answer over there (just copy&paste from the edit window, it's three clicks that way).
Unfortunately these late contributions do not tend to get the attention (votes) they deserve (IMHO again). This is a prime example for placing a bounty to draw attention to an old question.

Comment: A quick comment that highlights why you don't think something is a dupe is particularly helpful when the question pops up for review in the reopen queue, as the reviewer can simply agree (or not) with your logic and vote to reopen (or not) instead of having to start from scratch with an analysis of the questions and their differences.

Comment: p.s. congrats on 3K rep @Berwyn!

Comment: Here's one: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68399/what-is-the-meaning-of-this/68400#68400 The original answer didn't note that these are the fare basis codes. Thanks for the congrats :)

Comment: Maybe the mobile app suggestion on this one might be useful on the origina l question? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68613/passport-issues-september-2006-has-camera-symbol-is-it-valid/68614#68614

Comment: Maybe if a question is closed as a duplicate, an alert could be sent to anyone who has already provided an answer on that question, so they could do as you suggest in your answer? (@mts)

Comment: @Berwyn my answer was intended to be very general, please go ahead and post in the duplicate questions you found. An old answer need not be correct as you figured.

Comment: I was just trying to be general as well. I didn't really have anything that specific in mind, it was just a general feeling

Comment: @Berwyn regarding your suggestion, make that an own meta post as a feature-request (there's a tag for that). I find it great, you'll have my +1. And regarding the use of marking as dupes, feel free to be more active and also flag and vote to re-open, you now have the rep to :)